# How can I prevent an infinite loop in this situation?

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

```
cin>>num;
while (num < 1 || num > 3)
{
    cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
    cout << "Please insert the value range within 1 - 3... ";
    cin >> num;
}
```

How can prevent an infinite loop when I `cin` an alphabetic character? It will just show `Invalid input` and `Please insert the value range within 1 - 3...` when I input an alphabetic character.

Comment: Enter a 1, 2, or 3. Also make sure you actually modify `num` because you currently only modify `num1`, so `num` never changes.

Answer (score 4):

You're saving the result to `num1`, yet the loop is checking the contents of a variable called `num`. You have to be consistent in both places, otherwise the condition evaluation would never change, would it? Other than that, your logic looks fine.

Comment: What i means is when i input integers it will loop "Invalid input" and "Please insert the value range within 1 - 3..." for this is fine but when i input alphabet or any words it will loop infinity. So how can i input alphabet and it will loop one times only not loop infinity...

Comment: You need to test that `cin >> num` actually succeeded in reading a number. '`(cin >> num).good()`' will be false if you enter a non-digit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
while (num < 1 || num > 3)
{
    if (!isdigit(num))
    cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
    else
    {
    cout << "Please insert the value range within 1 - 3... ";
    cin >> num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

```
while (cout << "please insert a value between 1 and 3..." &&
        (cin >> num).good() &&
        (1 <= num && num <= 3))
    cout << num << endl;
```

Comment: The OP mentioned says he gets '`invalid input`' when he enters an alphabet (meaning I assume a character).  '`cin >> num`' does not throw when a character is input, but '`(cin >> num).good()`' will be false if he inputs a character and it will break out of loop.